# Using a Macro to format data on sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I run a small retail store and I've been tasked with creating inventory labels for our items.  I export a list of items from an inventory management software (AMan Pro) into Excel taking the items' Description, Quantity, Condition, SKU#, and Platform (video game platform).  I've got two Macros currently.  One will trim up the SKU to a usable format (gets rid of leading letters) and the other separates multiple quantity items out to separate rows.  (i.e. item #1 with a Quantity of 5 will be copied to 5 rows all with a quantity of 1)  That stuff works, but I think I'm doing some unnecessary steps that could be handled with a macro.

My AMan program spits out an Excel workbook with the items.  I then copy those items into my 'macro-enabled' workbook on sheet one and then run my macros.  Sheet two has the properly formatted data for the labels.  For example; it has formulas that trim the Description field to only use the first 60 characters.  (some of the descriptions are pretty long)

I'm feeling like that second sheet isn't really necessary.  I would like to copy the items into Sheet 1 and run a macro that does all of that formatting for me ***on*** sheet 1.

1. Separate items with multiple quanities onto separate rows (I do have
   a working macro for this.)
2. Remove leading letters from SKU (working macro) and then put SKU in seven digit number format (#######)
3. Reduce the Description to only the first 60 characters.
4. Reduce the Condition to only the first 2 characters.
5. Reduce the Platform to only the first 15 characters.

Here's my current macro code and a link to my spreadsheet.  Thanks in advance, guys.
[SKU_LABEL_FINAL.xlsm](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51462555/SKU_LABELS_FINAL.xlsm)

```
Sub ExpandRows()
Dim dat As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim rw As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheets(1).UsedRange
dat = rng

' Loop thru your data, starting at the last row
For i = UBound(dat, 1) To 2 Step -1
    ' If Quantity > 1
    If dat(i, 2) > 1 Then
        ' Insert rows to make space
        Set rw = rng.Rows(i).EntireRow
        rw.Offset(1, 0).Resize(dat(i, 2) - 1).Insert
        ' copy row data down
        rw.Copy rw.Offset(1, 0).Resize(dat(i, 2) - 1)
        ' set Quantity to 1
        rw.Cells(1, 2).Resize(dat(i, 2), 1) = 1
    End If
Next
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Replace What:="AManPro-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To format your SKUs into a 7 digit number format is pretty simple with what you have. You would just need to insert this line of code before the `End Sub` line

`Selection.NumberFormat = "0000000"`

You could trim the length of each cell when you parse through the data.

First, I would use some `Const` statements to note which columns are what, and what length they need to be. You could just use the numbers in the code, but this makes it easier to update things in the future if they change. Add below the final `Dim`

```
Const DESCRIPTIONLENGTH = 60
Const DESCRIPTIONCOLUMN = 2
```

Then as you loop through each row, you would then update the value of the cell - add below the `For i =...`

```
'Format each column's data
    dat(i, DESCRIPTIONCOLUMN).Value = Left(dat(i, DESCRIPTIONCOLUMN), DESCRIPTIONLENGTH)
```

I'm hoping the code for the description column will help you to build what you need for the other columns as well.

Comment: Thank you, sir.  I think that's exactly what I need.  With that example of the description code, I can definitely fix up the others.  Thanks again!